# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'C' was corrupted. occurred

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to make a matrix multiplication and addition code by making functions, but it is giving me an error, please help me fix it.
I am new to c++ and programming so it is quite difficult for me to understand array and pointers concept.
I have made the functions without pointers but it was giving the same output as this code. And was generating warning of overflow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void matrix(int arr[3][3])
{
    cout << "Matrix Input" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << "arr[" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "] = ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void printmatrix(int arr[3][3])
{
    cout << "Matrix" << endl;
    cout << "{";
    for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
    {
        cout << "{ ";
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
        {
            cout << arr[l][a] << " ";
        }
        cout << "}";
    }
    cout << "}";
}
int matrixMultiply(int *arr1, int *arr2, int *result)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                result[j] += arr1[k] * arr2[j];
            }
            arr1 += 3;
            arr2 += 3;
            result += 3;
        }
    }
    return *result;
}
int matrixAddition(int *arr1, int *arr2, int *result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            result[j] = arr1[j] + arr2[j];
        }
        arr1 += 3;
        arr2 += 3;
        result += 3;
    }
    return *result;
}
int main()
{
    int A[3][3], B[3][3], C[3][3], D[3][3] = { {0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0} };
    matrix(A);
    matrix(B);
    matrixMultiply(A[0], B[0], C[0]);
    matrixAddition(A[0], B[0], D[0]);
    cout << "Addition of matrix:" << endl;
    printmatrix(D);
    cout << endl << "Multiplication of matrix:" << endl;
    printmatrix(C);
}
```

output of code after inputting the values is:

```
Addition of matrix:
Matrix
{{ 6 -8 9 }{ 11 7 0 }{ 2 4 6 }}
Multiplication of matrix:
Matrix
{{ -858993430 -858993460 -858993460 }{ -858993460 -858993432 -858993460 }{ -858993460 -858993460 -858993446 }}
```

Comment: You are operating under the assumption that each matrix is laid out in a contiguous row-major order. In that case, each matrix is 9 `int`s back to back. If you look at matrixAddition, you have 9 iterations where each iteration shifts your pointers by 3 elements. The last iteration thus accesses element 27 which is clearly out of the range of the matrix.

Comment: @Botje but even if i shift pointer by 1 it still not works

Comment: Run your program under a debugger. Break in the main function. Record the addresses of all your matrices. Now step through the functions and see if they access out of bounds.